# error with pdo exec update statement?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Getting this **error** for the below... worked fine in **non-pdo** format :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

```php
// update user's current ip and current login date in db (prepared not required as no user input)
$db->exec("UPDATE test_users SET currIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], dtCurrLogin = UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE user = $user");
```

Comment: the type of column dtcurrlogin is set to what?

Comment: ok so you can just use mysqlquery as my answer below it will reslove the problem

Comment: I am doing everything with pdo... this is an example I got off a tutorial I am using - $affected_rows = $db->exec("UPDATE table SET field='value'");
echo $affected_rows.' were affected'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the array-index call to:

```
$db->exec("UPDATE test_users 
    SET currIP = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', 
        dtCurrLogin = UTC_TIMESTAMP() 
    WHERE user = $user");
```

---

I'd still suggest using `prepare` call.

```
$stm = $db->prepare("UPDATE test_users 
        SET currIP = :ip, 
            dtCurrLogin = UTC_TIMESTAMP() 
        WHERE user = :usr");
$stm->bindParam( ':ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stm->bindParam( ':usr', $user, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stm->execute();
```

Comment: I was staying away from prepared with this particular one because there is no user input involved... I would assume it would be faster and less resources without the prepared. Correct?

Comment: try to echo $user maybe is null

Comment: @user756659 If the `$user` is integer, then my first solution would work perfectly, otherwise change to `"... user = '" . $user . "'"`

Comment: Ended up with <code>$db->exec("UPDATE test_users SET currIP = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', dtCurrLogin = UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE user = '".$user."'");</code>  Are quotes required even when using variables?  I did not need anything for UTC_TIMESTAMP(), but in another area I could not use UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY and need to change to DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) for it to work...